# I want to compare and match two files and print them into one file

Tags: sed, perl

I have two files, file1 and file2

file1:

```
r11_abc_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9
r11_bcd_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.7
r11_acd_gkhsa 1.3 1.6 1.5
r11_xyz_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9
```

file2:

```
sd1_bcd_gkhsa 1.8 1.5 1.9
ab1_abc_gkhsa 1.6 1.4 1.5
sfs_xyz_gkhsa 1.4 1.6 1.4
sd1_acd_gkhsa 1.2 1.3 1.5
sfs_ryb_gkhsa 1.5 1.2 1.7
```

I want to match " abc , bcd, acd, and xyz" of file1 with file2. Whenever it matched with file2 I want to print it the following way.

Output:

```
r11_abc_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9     ab1_abc_gkhsa 1.6 1.4 1.5
r11_bcd_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.7     sd1_bcd_gkhsa 1.8 1.5 1.9
r11_acd_gkhsa 1.3 1.6 1.5     sd1_acd_gkhsa 1.2 1.3 1.5
r11_xyz_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9     sfs_xyz_gkhsa 1.4 1.6 1.4
sfs_ryb_gkhsa 1.5 1.2 1.7
```

can use Perl or sed. can someone give me ideas to work on it.

Comment: Are your search terms ("abc", "bcd", and so on) fixed, or do you want to search for every string that occurs in file1?

Comment: Also, what's the complete problem you are trying to solve? Help us better understand your problem by giving us more context — you might have fallen in the classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/235803) trap. And what forces you to use sed or Perl, but nothing else?

Comment: If your data were structured more cleanly, e.g. `abc r11 gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9`, you could [use `join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/join.html).

Comment: hi all, i tried this way.. first i grep abc, bcd,... in a file and then used foreach and grep commands to get it together.
    
       foreach _c ( "`cat strings_to_Compare`" )
        grep $_c -i file1 /' tr -d "\n"
         grep $_c -i file2
         end

Answer (score 0):

Using `join`,`sort`, and `sed`:

```
join -j 2 -t_ -a 1 -a 2  -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.9999,2.1,2.2,2.3 \
     <(sort -t_ -k2 file1) <(sort -t_ -k2 file2) | \
     sed 's/__/  /g;s/^ *//g' | sort
```

1. `sort` *file1* & *file2* using `bash`'s *process substitution, then...
2. Using `_` as a field separator, `join` the two sorted files on common instances of field #2, and also print singly any line from either file that doesn't match.  The nonexistent field `1.9999` separates each joined pair with an extra `_` to simplify step #3.
3. Clean up ugly bits of output with `sed`.
4. `sort` the results.

Output:

```
r11_abc_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9  ab1_abc_gkhsa 1.6 1.4 1.5
r11_acd_gkhsa 1.3 1.6 1.5  sd1_acd_gkhsa 1.2 1.3 1.5
r11_bcd_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.7  sd1_bcd_gkhsa 1.8 1.5 1.9
r11_xyz_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9  sfs_xyz_gkhsa 1.4 1.6 1.4
sfs_ryb_gkhsa 1.5 1.2 1.7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use plain `bash` arrays --

```
#read in the data from 2 files
unset arr1; declare -A arr1; 
while read -r -u3 line; do \
    i=${line%_*}; \
    i=${i#*_}; \
    arr1[$i]+=" $line"; \
done 3< <(cat f1 f2); \
exec 3<&-
#output array by iterating throug the keys
for k in "${!arr1[@]}"; do \
     echo ${arr1[$k]}; \
done | sort
```

Output --

```
r11_abc_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9 ab1_abc_gkhsa 1.6 1.4 1.5
r11_acd_gkhsa 1.3 1.6 1.5 sd1_acd_gkhsa 1.2 1.3 1.5
r11_bcd_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.7 sd1_bcd_gkhsa 1.8 1.5 1.9
r11_xyz_gkhsa 1.0 1.5 1.9 sfs_xyz_gkhsa 1.4 1.6 1.4
sfs_ryb_gkhsa 1.5 1.2 1.7
```